# My custom CSS is not taken into account

Tags: 8, theming

I add a CSS file (mymovies.css) to a custom form (SeenMovies) in a custom module (eric) with this code I inserted at the end of `buildForm`

```
$form['#attached']['library'][] = 'eric/mymovies';
```

and this code in `eric.libraries.yml`

```
mymovies:
  version: 1.x
  css:
    theme:
      css/mymovies.css: {}
```

But my css doesn't override `bootstrap.min.css` as you can see in Firefox inspector:
[image]

How can I fix that?

Comment: And how is Bootstrap attached? Your CSS seems to be attached first, then comes Bootstrap which overrides yours. Apart from that it doesn't make much sense to target a broad selector like an `<hr>` from a custom module on one form while using Bootstrap at the same time. You could simply fix that by being more specific in your CSS. Like `#myform hr { ... }` or even give your `<hr>` its own class and then it would be `hr.my-hr { ... }`. The more precise you are in your selectors the higher is the priority of your styles.

Comment: Considering what I can find in the page source: `<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/themes/contrib/onepage_zymphonies_theme/includes/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css?q9i5qg" />`I assume bootstrap is brought by the theme I use (onepage_zymphonies).

Comment: @leymannx `#seen-movies hr{...}` works fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I used the advice from @leymannx and changed my css to

```
#seen-movies hr{
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  border-top: 1px #808080 solid;
}
```

where 'seen-movies' is my form id.

Answer (score 1):

This question has nothing to do with Drupal but with CSS order of precedence. If more than one identical CSS rules are found, the last one takes precedence.

As @leymannx pointed in their comment, your page is loading first your CSS file, then Bootstrap. Just move your Bootstrap into a new library as you just did with 'mymovies', then add a dependency to 'mymovies'. Declaring it as a dependency, it will load first the need libraries, then the library being called.

**Edit - after saying you are using OnePage Zymphonies theme:**

If you check 'onepage_zymphonies_theme.libraries.yml' you will see that the Bootstrap library is defined. Following my answer:

```
mymovies:
  version: 1.x
  css:
    theme:
      css/mymovies.css: {}
  dependencies:
      - onepage_zymphonies_theme/bootstrap
```

Comment: But can't the CSS group and weight affect where this OP's stylesheet is in the order process, which will determine the specific rules in the cascade?

Comment: @devicaru As Bootstrap is there because of the theme I use (see my comment for @leymannx), I don't know hox to do what you suggest...

Comment: @gbmapo check my edit.

Comment: I changed my library to what you suggest. It's not working: still have hr rules from bootstrap over mine :-(

Comment: did you clear caché?

Comment: yes: cache cleared!

Comment: still not working? that makes nonsense...

Comment: I tried again, to be sure. Not working!

Answer (score -1):

Instead of adding an additional selector for all the css in future to override the bootstrap css you can try using the weight flag of libraries like this:

```
mymovies:
  version: 1.x
  css:
    theme:
      css/mymovies.css: { weight: N }
```

Just determine the weight of bootstrap library and replace `N` with the number greater than that.

In this way your mymovies.css will load after bootstrap css and you will no longer need to write that extra selector

Comment: Don't do this! Use `dependencies` instead!